# Why do we need Robot class when we have Actions class in selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, action, awtrobot

I was going through the selenium learning and when I was exploring interaction with keyboard and mouse topic, I found this code.
With the help of Robot class,perform Enter :

```
Robot r=new Robot();
r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

With the help of Actions class,perform Enter :

```
Actions action = new Actions(driver); 
action.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER).build().perform();
```

Why do we need both the class to perform same actions? What is the difference between Robot class and Actions class? 
TIA.

Comment: Selenium's `Actions` isn't bundled with the standard lib and requires a browser driver. `Robot` exists within the standard lib and doesn't require a browser driver.

Comment: @VinceEmigh : tnks for such a short and full explained answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Robot Class

[**Robot Class**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) is defined in [**java.awt**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/package-summary.html) package within [**java.desktop**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java.desktop-summary.html) module. This class is used to deal with the native system input events associated with *Test Automation* where control over the *Mouse* and *Keyboard* is needed. The primary purpose of *Robot Class* is to facilitate *Automated Testing* of Java platform implementations. Using *Robot Class* to generate input events differs from posting events to the *Java AWT event queue* or *AWT components* as using *Robot Class* events are generated in the platform's native input queue. As an example `Robot.mouseMove` will actually move the mouse cursor instead of just generating *Mouse Move Event*.

At this point it is worth to mention, some platforms requires special privileges or extensions to access low-level input control. If the current platform configuration does not allow input control, an [AWTException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/awt/AWTException.html) will be thrown when trying to construct Robot objects. For example, *X-Window systems* will throw the exception if the *XTEST 2.2 standard extension* is not supported (or not enabled) by the *X server*.

An Example :

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
// Press keys using robot. A gap of of 500 mili seconds is added after every key press
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_R);
Thread.sleep(500);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_U);
Thread.sleep(500);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_P);
Thread.sleep(500);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_A);
Thread.sleep(500);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_L);
Thread.sleep(500);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_I);
```

### Actions Class

[Actions Class](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html) is defined in [**org.openqa.selenium.interactions**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/package-summary.html) package and is the *User-Facing API* for emulating complex user gestures when using **Selenium**. While *Test Automation* through *Selenium* you can use this class rather than using the Keyboard or Mouse directly. *Actions Class* implements the *Builder Pattern* which can build a *CompositeAction* containing all actions specified by the below mentioned method calls :

- [**`build()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#build--)
- [**`click(WebElement target)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#click-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)
- [**`clickAndHold(WebElement target)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#clickAndHold-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)
- [**`contextClick(WebElement target)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#contextClick-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)
- [**`doubleClick(WebElement target)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#doubleClick-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)
- [**`dragAndDrop(WebElement source, WebElement target)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#dragAndDrop-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-)
- [**`moveToElement(WebElement target, int xOffset, int yOffset)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#moveToElement-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-int-int-)
- [**`perform()`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#perform--)
- [**`sendKeys(WebElement target, java.lang.CharSequence... keys)`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/interactions/Actions.html#sendKeys-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-java.lang.CharSequence...-)

An Example :

```
Actions act = new Actions(driver);
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement electronics = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li/a[@href='/electronics']")));
act.moveToElement(electronics).perform();
```

Answer (score 1):

The Main Difference is Actions class simulates with mouse and keyboard and Robot class enables the actual mouse and keyboard so you can see the movement of the mouse cursor.
For more Details please Click on this Link -> [Robot class in Selenium](https://stqatools.com/selenium-robot-class/)